# Tensorflow - Minimize with Complex Gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, complex-numbers, gradient

I have been trying to implement gradient descent with respect to complex parameter/weights in TensorFlow, but I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/reg/complex_gradients.py", line 15, in <module>
gate_gradients=optimizer.GATE_NONE)
   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 196, in minimize
grad_loss=grad_loss)
   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 257, in compute_gradients
self._assert_valid_dtypes([v for g, v in grads_and_vars if g is not None])
   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 379, in _assert_valid_dtypes
dtype, t.name, [v for v in valid_dtypes]))
ValueError: Invalid type tf.complex64 for w:0, expected: [tf.float32, tf.float64, tf.float16].
```

I boiled down my code to this to recreate the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.complex64)
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

initial_values = tf.complex(real=tf.random_uniform([100, 100]), imag=tf.random_uniform([100, 100]))
 weigths = tf.Variable(initial_values, name='w', dtype=tf.complex64)

loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.complex_abs(tf.matmul(x, weigths)) - y, name='loss')

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss,
                       global_step=0.001,
                       gate_gradients=optimizer.GATE_NONE)
```

What did I miss? Does Tensorflow simply not support complex numbers? Any suggestions to make it work anyway? Would be thankful for any help.

Comment: you could represent complex in terms of real parameters, c = (a + i b) and optimize with respect to a,b instead of c